# Easy calculator doesn't work - No errors, but also no results

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm fairly new to JavaScript (even to programming, but ..) and trying to script an "easy" calculator. What I'm currently doing is trying to figure out how to do it, but I think I almost got it. For now I just want everything to work properly and only implemented an addition.

However... When pressing the "="-button it just does nothing. It throws out no results and no errors either.

```
<input type="button" name="ergebnis" value="=" onClick="ausgabe();">
```

Here is the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/bbcCB/
Please excuse the partially bilingualism of my functions, but I'm speaking German and sometimes the meaning of something is easier for me to understand in English.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your delDisplay function is clearing it.

Comment: It seems also that your tmpval1() functions does not jump in the correct if because if i put a letter in it, it does not prompt the error message.

Comment: Also I don't want to strip you of your adventure in this calculator project but you might want to check out the eval() function in javascript. It might be desirable.

Comment: Errors I've seen: `window.tmpval=""` should be `window.tmpval==""`. Some self-closing tags are not closed. You can't call `isNaN` of a string. I'd suggest a complete rewrite (with a help of a tutorial).

Comment: BTW I just wanted to say, keep it up and have fun.  Just don't' use eval EVER.  I mean seriously no one will like you.  Also look up global abatement in js.  Once you feel ok with that or even before watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook and read his book.  If this stuff speaks to you it will help jump start you.

Comment: I tried to take your example and make it a module but there are still lots of issue, I hope this get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/eLuDt/2/  I added jquery into it just to save me some time, but you can do it anyway you want.

Answer (score 3):

That code is not very well written. nor is it functional. It makes heavy use of *global variables* (window.X), which is discouraged these days due to global variables pollution.

Here are some better alternatives if you're looking for something to learn from:

- http://kalyan-city.blogspot.com/2009/11/simple-javascript-calculator-code.html
- http://www.webestools.com/scripts_tutorials-code-source-8-javascript-calculator-buttons-calculator-keyboard-support-operations-modulo.html
- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-css3-calculator

Answer (score 0):

I can't really read your code so here's a simple example of how I personally would of wrote this.  http://jsfiddle.net/mtmvm/3/

html

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="" />

<input type="button" onclick="num_add()" id="plus" value="+" />Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

JS
    var number = 0;

```
var num_add = function () {
    var box = document.getElementById("input");
    var output = document.getElementById("result");
    console.log(box.value);
    number += parseFloat(box.value);
    box.value = "";
    output.innerHTML = number;
};
```

Naturally this has lots of problems mostly dealing with the fact that these functions are in the global scope meaning they may overwrite any other functions with the same name.

some good videos on javascript are David Crockford's javascript the good parts. http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=javascript+the+good+parts&page=&utm_source=opensearch

here's a really good post on learning javascript, [The best way to learn javascript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-best-way-to-learn-javascript/)

Comment: I like this way, but it doesn't work properly for me. When trying it out by choosing a simple addition (f.e. 5+5). After clicking the "equals"-button nothing changes. The last entered number just stays there. If I enter another number (f.e. (the existing) 5 + 1) and press "equals" it gives out 10, which makes no sense (5+5+1 != 10).

Comment: Yeah it was a bit funky, I changed it so it makes more sense I think, getting rid of the ='s button which may be a bit weird for some people but I think it makes sense. http://jsfiddle.net/mtmvm/3/